# For a service that is only restricted to 15 cities across 9 states, when is it feasible to introduce location search?

Tags: search, localization, geolocation, location-service

The service is only offered in 15 cities, the number of disappointment search results (0 results) is much greater than actually getting results.

What other factors should I consider to make this decision?

Would you recommend no location search and a simple browsing by city to start? and only introduce search after more cities are incorporated?

How many cities warrant a location search?

Comment: Another factor you should consider is lead generation. When a search returns 0 results, you can leverage that as an opportunity to collect their email address so that they can be notified when you add their city. Not only does this provide the user with a positive action, it provides you with information on where to expand next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If search is overwhelmingly disappointing, than it might be good to consider simply showing a map of all the locations so the user can clearly see where the service is in relation to themselves. Then as nessahead stated, give them hope with an email capture that lets them know the service is coming to their area.

(And don't forget to follow through with that promise)